# java arrays with objects and refernce

Tags: java

I have a basic doubt, when I was analyzing object and reference.

```
int a; //here we are creating an object a of type integer

Integer b=new Integer(); // here we are creating a reference variable b points to an object of type Integer in heap.
```

What is the advantage of each one ? where to use "int a" and the other one?

In case of arrays:

```
int[] a=new int a[5];
```

if "int a" is possible why " int a[5] " is not possible, because the below code throws null pointer exception:

```
int a[5];
a[0]=10;
System.out.println(a[0]);  //gives null pointer exception
```

The code works well when:

```
 int[] a=new int[5];  
 a[0]=5;  
 System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Why in case the former case its excepting a reference needs to be created when "int a" works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int a` is declaring a primitive variable, called `a`, that is of type `int`.  Primitives are not objects, but arrays are of primitives are objects.

Arrays are objects, but they are a special type of object that Java has special syntax for using.  When you are using `int[] a` you are declaring an object, called `a`, whose type is an array of ints.  When you assign it with `a = new int[5]`, it is as though you are calling a constructor in a special way.  It is as though you were really calling some constructor and passing the size as a parameter: `a = new IntArray(5)` or something.  Java gives you special syntax so that this type of construct is not needed.

Similarly, when you say `a[0] = 5`, it is as though you are calling a method on your object `a`, but Java gives you special syntax for this.  It's almost like you are calling `a.setValue(0, 5)`, but Java gives nice syntax so that this type of thing is not necessary either.

So if you tried to declare `int a[5]`, that would be like trying to declare a variable using `new IntArray(5)`...that doesn't make sense as a variable declaration.  You would basically be using a call to the constructor to declare a variable, which wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is because int isn't Object - it's primitive type and it cannot be null. 
Integer is object and reference can be null.

```
int a[] = new int[5]; //is legal and all elements has 0
Integer a[] = new Integer[5]; //is legal too but in this case you have null
```

Common case of using Integer is Collections, in this case it has to be object, e.g:

```
List<int> list = new ArrayList<int>          // Illegal
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>  // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

`int` is the primitive type that `Integer` uses. `int` is more efficient as `Integer` is a class with methods, thus uses more memory.

The first array example doesn't work because with just `int a[5];` you're merely creating a reference, not the actual values (thus throwing a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it). With `int[] a=new int[5];` you create the actual array to use, so after that you can use the values.

Answer (score 0):

a) First of all, `int a;` doesn't declare an object. it's just a var to hold an integer.

b) Always use primitive datatypes over wrapper classes to avoid the overhead of creating an object just to represent a primitive.

c) `int a[5]` is a reference to an array of 5 integers pointing to `null`, hence `a[0]` makes no sense

d) the code `int[] a = new int[5];` works properly because you've initialized `a` to an array of 5 integers, each of which will have a default value of 0.

e) `int a` is a primitive data type declaration hence it doesn't necessarily need to be initialized unless it's a local variable. `int[] a`, however, is an int array reference, and since arrays are Objects in Java, you've to initialize before using them.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`int a[5];` is understood implicitly as `int a[5] = null;`</strike> (declaration is invalid in java). `int[] a=new int[5];` creates an array of length 5 with each element of the array containing a **default value** of `0`. `Integer[] a = new Integer[5]` creates an array of `Integer` of length 5, all elements have `null` as default value.

There are ways to initialize an array (Just an extra note). Example:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

This creates an array of `int` of length 5, and each element (counting from 0) are assigned values from the braces `{}` starting from the left to the right.

Furthermore, `int` is a primitive type, so JVM creates a memory space for the size of `int` (e.g 4 bytes int) while `Integer` is an `Object` so JVM creates a memory space to hold the full object of `Integer` (which is bigger than the memory space of `int`).

> where to use "int a" and the other one

Use `Integer` if you need to use Generics (since you can't use primitive types in generics but `int[]` or primitive arrays are allowed) or need functions from the `Integer` class. Else, storage of values to a persistent storage, use `int`.

Comment: I think `int a[5];` is a syntax error in Java, as well as `int a[5] = null;` would be. See [JLS §8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#40898), there is nothing inside the brackets.